# iOS Printing and HTML formatter - Which interpreter and how fancy?

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, printing, xcode4

I have an iOS 5 application that sends a job to the print que. I have all of that code working fine and I'm using the HTML formatter to create the document (UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter). Right now I have a very basic HTML string that I am using for testing but want to flesh it out further.

1. Which HTML engine is used to interpret the HTML string that is passed to UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter? Or, in other words, what is the best way for me to test my HTML string outside of XCode? Can I just create a text file and then view it in Safari? Would that give me the best approximation of what it will look like when printed from iOS?
2. How fancy can I get with the HTML in the UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter? I assume that I'll have to use all inline styles? Are there some examples out there of HTML strings that are sent to UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter to create rich documents? I just want to get an idea of what's possible with this combination.

Answer (score 0):

You can test iOS printing in the Simulator, using the iOS Printer Simulator app. The `UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter` will render through WebKit. Imagine the HTML string is a single-page HTML document. That is basically the limitations of the formatter, although I believe you can also link to external style sheets and images too.

Comment: I know I can use the Simulator, I'm doing that now. I'm thinking more in terms of if I want to send this to a designer. Can I just have them test in Safari? I think that uses WebKit too. Or what other way can I test the HTML that *does not* use the Simulator.

Comment: HTML testing should be fine in Safari, or Chrome.